# comparing two dataframes get number repetitions

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with column names:

```
DF1:
+------------+
|   colsNames|
+------------+
|col1        |
|col2        |
|col3        |
+------------+
```

And a dataframe with arrays of values:

```
DF2:
+------------+
|         set|
+------------+
|[11, 20]    |
|[1]         |
|[10, 17, 54]|
+------------+
```

And finally, another dataframe with, generally, biggers arrays than DF2 with numbers:

```
DF3:
+--------------------+
|             origin |
+--------------------+
|[11, 17, 1, 2, 3]   |
|[1, 17, 54, 66, 1]  |
|[11, 20, 10, 20]    |
+--------------------+
```

Each row of DF2 is compared against all values of column origin in DF3 and create a columns with the total matches between all elements. A result would be like this:

```
resultDF:
+--------------------+------------+------------+------------+
|             origin |        col1|        col2|        col3|
+--------------------+------------+------------+------------+
|[11, 17, 1, 2, 3]   |           1|           1|           1|
|[1, 17, 54, 66, 1]  |           0|           2|           2| 
|[11, 20, 10, 20]    |           3|           0|           1|
+--------------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Explanation for the first row of this resultDF(the rest are the same):

- compare [11,20] against [11, 17, 1, 2, 3] with result 1 (just appears one time number 11)
- compare [11,20] against [1, 17, 54, 66, 1] with result 0
- compare [11,20] against [11, 20, 10, 20]  with result 3 (two times appears number 20 and just once number 11).
- By row order, we add a column with DF1 values with the previous results. DF1 and DF2 has the same row numbers.